# MpCharts Android xAxis values

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

Im just getting out of mind probably some easy thing that i just cant catch with my blind eyes.
I cant get xAxis values to group it just sets the values like index + something not index or getX() from BarEntry is showing up

this is my code, a little messy

```
mBarChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

mBarChart.setPinchZoom(false);
mBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
mBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

XAxis xAxis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        list.add(new BarEntry(i, 0.5f));
        list2.add(new BarEntry(i,0.9f));
    }
BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(list,"Set 1");
set1.setColor(Color.rgb(104, 241, 175));

BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(list2,"Set 2");
set2.setColor(Color.rgb(200, 241, 175));


List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(set1);
dataSets.add(set2);
BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

mBarChart.setData(data);
mBarChart.groupBars(0,0.1f,0.1f);
mBarChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
});

mBarChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
mBarChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);

xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(0 + mBarChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(1, 0.2f) * 7);
CustomMarkerView customMarkerView = new CustomMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view);

customMarkerView.setChartView(mBarChart);

mBarChart.setMarker(customMarkerView);
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
mBarChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();

mBarChart.invalidate();`
```

any tips?
https://postimg.org/image/dj3lp3lwt/
edit: image dont want to show up :)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt solved my problem but installing 2.2.5 version not 3+ made it easy.